# posting data to php via url

Tags: php, html, url, post

I have the following simple form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Upload Lab Data</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="POST">
            <input name="ip" type="text" />
            <input name="data" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the following `php` script:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
        $data = $_POST['data']  . "\n";
        $ip = $_POST['ip'] . "\n";
        $ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/' . $ip, $data, LOCK_EX);
        if($ret === false) {
            die('There was an error writing this file');
        }
        else {
            echo "$ret bytes written to file";
        }
    }
    else {
        die('no post data to process');
    }
?>
```

It works fine, but how can I modify (or use as-is) so that I can submit the `ip` and `data` fields via the url? My end goal is to be able to submit data from a java program running on another server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

```
<form action="test.php" method="GET">
```

Then, deal with `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` in your PHP script

Comment: Okay, that worked. Only issue now is that the $ip variable (my filename) has an "?" appended to the end of it when it gets written. Is there a way to remove that?

Comment: try removing `. "\n"` from `$ip = $_POST['ip'] . "\n";`